# Median of a frequency distribution in vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a vertica table that contains data like

```
num_emails  num_users
1           1000
10          100
25          50
```

Where (1, 1000) means 1000 users received 1 email.
The median of this distribution is 1.

What's the best way to do that in SQL/Vertica? 
I looked at https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/MEDIANAnalytic.htm, but it seems to work only if the column is repeated n times (as opposed to a row being (column_val, n)).

Comment: what's the expected output? the data you are looking at i assume, is aggregated. just use the rows from the original table to calculate the median.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cumulative sum and arithmetic:

```
select avg(num_emails)
from (select t.*, sum(num_users) over (order by num_emails) as running_num_users,
             sum(num_users) over () as total_num_users
      from t
     ) t
where (running_num_users - num_users) * 2 <= total_num_users and
      running_num_users * 2 >= total_num_users;
```

The logic here is to get the point where the running total is half of the total count.  The `avg()` is because is some special cases, I think that two records could satisfy the conditions -- if there are an even number of users and the median is between two groups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is not the final answer - I don't think you supplied the right sample data. I tried both possible MEDIAN() expressions, and they don't really reveal a lot of information:

```
WITH input(num_emails,num_users) AS (
          SELECT  1,1000
UNION ALL SELECT 10,100
UNION ALL SELECT 25,50
)
SELECT
  *
, MEDIAN(num_users)  OVER() AS median_users
, MEDIAN(num_emails) OVER() AS median_emails
FROM input;

num_emails|num_users|median_users|median_emails
         1|    1,000|         100|           10
        10|      100|         100|           10
        25|       50|         100|           10
```

Can you supply data that we can play with?

Marco the Sane

Comment: forget this one - took a while to understand what you're after - I think Gordon Linoff's is the one you should look at ...